# Defining constants in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, constants

I have mulitple tables across 3 HTML pages , the heading of these tables are to remain same i.e .

```
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>MyHeading</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

I want to store the `MyHeading` string in a constant and use it across HTML pages in all my tables.
I am constrained to use pure HTML and javascript.
How do i do this in pure HTML i.e. storing static text in some constants so that I could reuse them across HTML pages

Comment: HTML has no concept of variables, constants or anything "dynamic". It's purely a *markup language*.

Comment: Sorry but how is this question a duplicate of the related question? Where is OP answer there?

Comment: I wanted to post an answer but the question was closed. take a look in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcs4qy99/) I made. You can share the JS part across your html files and it will replace placeholders with your `const`. Side Note: you can change `const` to `var` if you want more [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Okay thanks . Is this how we usually achieve maintainability in HTML ?

Comment: No my friend it is a possible hack. A working one, but still a hack. :) Usually to achieve it you should use some third party js but you mentioned you cannot use any :)

Answer (score 2):

IN HTML it is not possible. Either u have use some templating language and javascript. By using javascript, here is your answer

```js
var length = document.getElementsByClassName('head').length;
for(var i=0; i< length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('head')[i].innerHTML = "Demo Head";
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr><th class="head">heading</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr><th class="head">heading</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess this will work if we have multiple tables in the same HTML page.For a table in different HTML page i will have to rewrite the js code to populate the `<thead>` inner html . It does not achieve the benefit of maintainability which is the reason i wanted to have a constant. So, are you suggesting to keep the js script in some common place and the multiple HTML pages can call the js function which populates the `<thead>` on document ready?